# Multi level expandablelistview not expanding to last child

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have multi level expandablelistview with 5 levels. Upto 3 levels all the child are visible, later at 4th level i have few items missing and in 5th level i can see only 1 item. Each level have 4 elements and that is fixed. It seems that expandablelist has all the items but something wrong with height. So i will have to correct this height settings to get the display right. I had changed the MeasureSpec mode to exactly for the value 2300 and everything was perfect but it did not looked good as there were lot of free space when 3rd and 4th level were not expanded.

I have set the expandablelistview height to match_parent

Updated: with code information

This is the script for 3 Level, 1st Level, 2nd level are of similar ones

```html
private class Level3 extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LEVELS[] level;
        pratyantarDasha(LEVELS[] level){
            this.level = new planetData[level.length];
            System.arraycopy(level,0,this.level,0,level.length);
        }
        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            int height=groupPosition*72;
            final CustExpListview level4 = new CustExpListview(ctx);
            level4.setAdapter(new Level4(level[groupPosition].nextLevel));
            level4.setGroupIndicator(ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx,R.drawable.expand_collapse));
            final int[] lastExpPosition = {-1};
            level4.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    if (lastExpPosition[0] != -1 && groupPosition != lastExpPosition[0]) {
                        level4.collapseGroup(lastExpPosition[0]);
                    }
                    lastExpPosition[0] = groupPosition;
                }
            });
             level4.setPadding((int)ctx.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dp2)*5,(int)ctx.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dp2),(int)ctx.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dp2),(int)ctx.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dp2));
            return level4;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null ) {
                LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inf.inflate(R.id.textViewLayout4Exp, parent,false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.planet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expTV);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.value.setText(String.valueOf(level[groupPosition].value));
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

    }
```

4th Level script

```html
private class Level4 extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LEVELS[] level;
        Level4(LEVELS[] level){
            this.level = new LEVELS[level.length];
            System.arraycopy(level,0,this.level,0,level.length);
        }
        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null ) {
                LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inf.inflate(R.id.textViewLayout4Exp, parent,false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.planet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expTV);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.planet.setText(String.valueOf(level[groupPosition].nextLevel[childPosition].value));
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                                 View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null ) {
                LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inf.inflate(R.id.textViewLayout4Exp, parent,false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.value = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expTV);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.value.setText(String.valueOf(level[groupPosition].value));
            
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

    }
```

This is the custom expandablelistview class

```html
 public class CustExpListview extends ExpandableListView {
        
        public CustExpListview(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(99999,MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
```

Comment: update your question with code written and array for populating listview data to take a look

Comment: @AmodGokhale is right ,kindly update your question with some of your code stuff which you have tried.